# Append text to JTextArea in a try catch block

Tags: java, swing, sockets, append, event-dispatch-thread

I try to append several statustext messages to a JTextArea while downloading a file from a socket. first i declared

```
private static JTextArea tArea;
```

and initiate it in my main function. thats working fine. i also have a menu to start a socket within a function in the menu. ive called it test() (for testing purposes.

My problem is, that the second status message doesnt append to the JTextArea until the download is finished. i also output some other status messages during the process and all of them appends after the socket is closed instead of during the process at the time it happens.

Edit: I think its a good article to understand the invoke later function so i will post this link for others who have problems like me. http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml Because of this link i understand it.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: thank you please could you explain me why the first append statement is executing, when this is necessary?

Comment: *"but can you explain me.."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson i hope my example is ok. thank you.